How can I change the resolution for DRM?
I need to change the standard resolution for my DRM mode.
How can I achieve that?
When I do cat on
cat /sys/class/drm/card0/card0-HDMI-A-1/modes

1920x1080
1920x1080
1920x1080
1280x720
1280x720
1280x720
720x576
720x576
720x480
720x480

The problem is my HDMI screen cannot support 1920x1080. My HDMI screen support 1280x720 and below.
So how can I tell DRM to not use 1920x1080?

What's your DRM client? In other words, are you running on a framebuffer console, or are you running X11 or Wayland? And what's the name of your display driver, i.e. if you run ls -l /sys/class/drm/card0/device/driver, what is the last element of the target path of that symbolic link?

@telcoM Wayland here. The problem is that I do not find any folder named driver. Most of them are symbolic links.

/sys/class/drm/card0/device/driver should be a symbolic link, where does it point to?

@telcoM Well, it's diffcult to copy and paste but it's not a symbolic link. It's a folder and it leads to more other folders.

Modern display drivers will generally auto-detect the "best" display resolution according to the display's EDID information. You can view that information in human-readable format with a command like:
cat /sys/class/drm/card0-HDMI-A-1/edid | parse-edid

But it sounds like your display's EDID may be telling a boastful lie, if it indicates 1920x1080 as available and it cannot actually be used. Or maybe you're using an extra-long HDMI cable and the signal degradation caused by the cable length is just enough to make the signal become unusable on 1920x1080, but smaller resolutions are fine.
You could try adding a boot option, as described here:
https://davejansen.com/add-custom-resolution-and-refresh-rate-when-using-wayland-gnome/
In your case, the boot option you'd need would be something like:
video=HDMI-A-1:1280x720@75

(The @75 part specifies the refresh rate; adjust as needed.)
For a full documentation of the video= option syntax, see:
https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/fb/modedb.html
